# Compile adb source to generate adb binary

Tags: android, adb

I followed the instruction specified in link http://mancoosi.org/~abate/build-android-adb-debian-sid-amd64

But i am encountering below error

```
make out/host/linux-x86/bin/adb

============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=AOSP
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2
TARGET_PRODUCT=full
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.2.0-36-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-12.04-precise
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=OPENMASTER
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
make: *** No rule to make target `out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libcrypto_static_intermediates/export_includes', needed by `out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/adb_intermediates/import_includes'.  Stop.
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Export includes file: system/core/libzipfile/Android.mk -- out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libzipfile_intermediates/export_includes
Export includes file: external/zlib/Android.mk -- out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libunz_intermediates/export_includes
```

Can anybody help me in pointing out what exactly is the error about and what should I do to fix this error?

Highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Signed up just to answer this, in case anyone else comes across it.

You need to also clone external/openssl now because newer versions (as of 2014-05) link statically against libcrypt.

I also needed to clone external/stlport

Comment: Also had to clone external/libcxxabi, prebuilts/clang/darwin-x86/host/3.6, all repos are listed : https://android.googlesource.com/